# What does exactly happen if I make a new repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working around with git and I'm really curious...

So I have my remote repository on gitlab and I push everything merge etc. and its fine.

I used the HTTPS link and created a new Repository that is different then the origin one, but what does that really create?

What is the difference between origin and created repository by me?

If I push changes from both of them they still go to gitlab and update accordingly?

Not sure what exactly happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two repositories: the one on the **gitlab server**, and the **local clone** you have made.

Cloning a github repository creates a copy of that repository locally on the computer where you run the `git clone` command.

By default this creates a branch called master which is **tracking** the remote branch called origin/master.

You can see the remotes registered in the repository by calling `git remote -v` the `-v` flag will show a more verbose output. Here you can see that the remote called origin, is the github repository.

Answer (score 0):

They are both clones of the repository from Gitlab. You can make as many clones as you like, when you push your changes they will all update the same repo on Gitlab. This allows a group of users to all collaborate on the same repo and set/get changes.

Lots of documentation on how git works: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics